# Ng-click not getting fired on triggering click from another module in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a form carousel created and injected in my module.

In the form carousel there is a button used to navigate to next field.

From my app i want to call this button when tab out of my field.
Here is my code.

```
var testFile = angular.module('testModule',['new-form-carousel','ngAnimate']);

testFile.controller('mainController',['$scope',function(s){
    s.data = {'name':'','password':''}

    s.pintThem = function(){
        console.log(s.data);
    }

    s.callNext = function(){

        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log($('a[ng-click="next()"]'));
            $('a[ng-click="next()"]').trigger('click');
        },10);

    }
}]);
```

here is my controller.

Here is the field i want to call the next method from

```
 <div>
            Name: <input type="text" ng-model="data.name" ng-blur="callNext()">
        </div>
```

**new-form-carousel starts here**
Here is the form carousel directive:

```
formCarousel.directive('carousel', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        controller: 'CarouselController',
        require: 'carousel',
        templateUrl: '../app/html/carousel.html',
        scope: {
            interval: '=',
            noTransition: '=',
            noPause: '='
        },

        link:function(scope,element,attrs,controller){

        }
    };
}]);
```

Here the html of the above directive:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" ng-click="prev()" ng-show="slides.length > 1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" ng-click="next()" ng-show="slides.length > 1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

Onblur from my html i want to call the next() method of the carousel.

Comment: can you create a plunker or fiddle..?

Comment: 1. Use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`. 2. You should manipulate `DOM` inside `directive`.

Comment: I dont want to touch that directive as it has to be used in different places. Hence i was looking at some kind of fix where i can call the next() method or call the next slide of carousel when i tab  out of the input field

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue that i was facing.

Instead of using jquery selector and trigger i used angular selector and triggerhandler and it is working fine.

Here is the fix:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        angular.element( document.querySelector('a[ng-click="next()"]')).triggerHandler('click');
        },10);
```